# Reference list of constants from Spring JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-el

Our client's library contains a couple of Java Classes with a lot of constants in the form of static ints:

```
public class Filter {
    public static final class COMPARATOR {
        public static final int EQUALS = 1;
        public static final int NOTEQUALS = 2;
        ...
    }
}
```

The challenge is I want to use these constants in a JSP Page. Because this is a Spring project I am attempting to use the spring eval tag:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<spring:eval var="equals" expression="T(com.model.Filter$COMPARATOR).EQUALS"/>
```

While the above works, I would need to define an eval individually for every single constant and there can be hundreds of these guys. Is there any way to avoid doing that? I'd like something like this:

```
<spring:eval var="COMPARATOR" expression="T(com.model.Filter$COMPARATOR)"/>
```

where I can then use this syntax: **${COMPARATOR.EQUALS}** (as is, this gives a javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException).

Answer (score 0):

#### TypeLocator

We can skip the full qualified name if we specify type locator as following shows:

```
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setTypeLocator(typeName -> {
  try {
    return Class.forName("com.github.zzt93.syncer.util." + typeName);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
  }
});
Class testClass = parser.parseExpression("T(SpringELTest)").getValue(context, Class.class);
System.out.println(testClass);
```

Runnable example is from [here](https://github.com/zzt93/syncer/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/zzt93/syncer/util/SpringELTest.java#L97).

#### tld

However, as far as I know, for now, [Spring tld](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-tld.html#spring.tld.eval) not support set evaluation context when get value.

So, we can define our own tags but use spring el to evaluate:

```
public class EvalTag extends TagSupport {
  private Object bean;
  private String propertyExpression; //Ex: 'model.sharingTocs'
  private String var;

  @Override
  public int doEndTag() throws JspException {
    try {
      // evaluate it as above code show
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new JspTagException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    return EVAL_PAGE;
  }
}
```

---

Hope this helpful.